# Proving properties of Hermitian conjugate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, terminology

I have three properties:

- If $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ are Hermitian operators. Then $\hat{A}\hat{B}$ is Hermitian provided $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ also commute $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]=0$
- If $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ are Hermitian operators and  $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ also commute, then $\hat{A}+\hat{B}$ is Hermitian
- If $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ are Hermitian operators, and  $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ do not commute, then $\hat{A}\hat{B}+\hat{B}\hat{A}$ is Hermitian

I am trying to prove all these properties.

---

1st one:

[image]

---

For the second one I'm struggling, as I do not know how to expand $(\hat{A}+\hat{B})^\dagger$

Comment: If two operators are hermitian, then their sum is hermitian; regardless whether they commute or not. Also the third statement is independent of the commutator of both operators. One can prove that $(\hat{A} + \hat{B})^{\dagger} = \hat{A}^{\dagger} + \hat{B}^{\dagger}$, which follows from the linearity of an inner product.

Comment: I'd be interested where you got these properties from.

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-51-quantum-theory-of-radiation-interactions-fall-2012/lecture-notes/MIT22_51F12_Ch2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

As Jakob commented, to prove identities of that kind it is often good to go back to the definition of the adjoint operator as arising from an inner product. **Given** an inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ and an operator $\hat{A}$, one **defines** the adjoint operator $\hat{A}^\dagger$ to be the operator that satisfies
$$(v,\hat{A}w) = (\hat{A}^\dagger v,w)$$
for all vectors $v,w$ (on a more technical note, one might have to restrict the condition from "all vectors" to "those vectors where the quantities are defined", but that is typically omitted in introductory QM lectures). With that, you can prove $(\hat{A}\hat{B})^\dagger = \hat{B}^\dagger \hat{A}^\dagger$ by
$$((\hat{A}\hat{B})^\dagger v,w) \stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=} (v,\hat{A}\hat{B}w) = (v,\hat{A}(\hat{B}w)) \stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=} (\hat{A}^\dagger v,\hat{B}w)
\stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=} (\hat{B}^\dagger(\hat{A}^\dagger v),w)
= (\hat{B}^\dagger\hat{A}^\dagger v,w).$$
Analogous to that, and just using the linearity of the inner product, i.e.
$$(v, w + \lambda u) = (v, w) + \lambda(v,u)$$
with vectors $v,w,u$ and a scalar $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, you can figure it out. Try it and comment if that works, otherwise I'll add another edit.

---

If the inner product notation is unfamiliar, replace braces with bras and kets and write greek letters,
$$\langle \psi | \hat{A} \phi \rangle\ \sim (v,\hat{A}w)$$

Answer (score 0):

Taking Hermitian Conjugate is simply taking Complex Conjugate and then Transpose, both operations are linear so their composition is also linear:

$$(\hat{A}+\hat{B} )^{\dagger}$$
$$=((\hat{A}+\hat{B} )^{T})^{*}$$
$$=(\hat{A}^{T}+\hat{B}^{T} )^{*}$$
$$=(\hat{A}^{T})^{*}+(\hat{B}^{T} )^{*}$$
$$=\hat{A}^{\dagger}+\hat{B}^{\dagger}$$
$$=\hat{A}+\hat{B} $$

In fact it doesn't matter that $\hat{A} \text{ and } \hat{B} $ commute, their sum is Hermitian in general.

For the last one there is a similar process except when you do the transpose you have to the order of multiplication, but then by switching the order of addition you obtain the same thing back again.

Comment: That's a bit circular isn't it? How would you show that $(A + B)^* =A^* + B^*$ or $(A +B)^T = A^T + B^T$?

Comment: The first one is is obvious for Matrices and Linear Maps alike, just show that the real part of the LHS is equal to the real part of the RHS and the same for imaginary part, real and imaginary part can be expressed as Re{C}=(C+C*)/2, Im{C}=(C+C*)/(2i)

Comment: Second one is obvious for Matrices (just take each element and show that they add), but for Linear Maps one must consider the action of A+B on a vector in its domain, and then show that linearity holds for the action of (A+B)^T on its codomain, this is also a pretty proof result as well

Comment: This answer is a bit problematic on the math side. For once, it introduces the transpose of an operator, which is only defined via a dual vector space. And secondly and more importantly, it introduces the complex conjugate of an operator. Complex conjugation is defined for complex numbers and by that functions on those numbers and by that one can expand it to operators, but I think it requires a lot more technical definitions and I'm not sure if it truly comes out the same thing as the adjoint operator in all cases.

Comment: See for instance https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110013/complex-conjugate-of-momentum-operator